# GlassMapper - GetItem<T>() method is failing to get item as specific type

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper

I'm trying to get item using GlassMapper as follow:

```
var myCustomObj=SitecoreContext.GetItem<IMy_Custom_Type>(itemId);
```

But `myCustomObj` is always null.

When I try to get the item as `IGlass_Base` object, it works:

```
var myCustomObj=SitecoreContext.GetItem<IGlass_Base>(itemId);
```

Edited:
Here is how the IMy_Custom_Type looks:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// IMy_Custom_Type Interface
    /// <para></para>
    /// <para>Path: /sitecore/templates/User Defined/###/Pages/My Custom Type</para>    
    /// <para>ID: dfacd744-0cf8-4917-922c-4baeb07dfe35</para>   
    /// </summary>
    [SitecoreType(TemplateId=IMy_Custom_TypeConstants.TemplateIdString, AutoMap = true )] //, Cachable = true
    public partial interface IMy_Custom_Type : IGlassBase , global::SC.Global.Models.TemplateModels.Base_Templates.IMetadata, global::SC.Global.Models.TemplateModels.Base_Templates.IBase_Background_Image
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The My Custom field.
        /// <para></para>
        /// <para>Field Type: Multilist</para>      
        /// <para>Field ID: 43388fa5-a02a-425d-ae31-d94a12860748</para>
        /// <para>Custom Data: </para>
        /// </summary>
        [SitecoreField(IMy_Custom_TypeConstants.MyCustomFieldName)]
        IEnumerable<Guid> My_Custom_Field  {get; set;}
        :
        :
        // Few more fields          

    }
```

Comment: Is it `templateID` or is it `itemID`? what it the code of your `IMy_Custom_Type`?

Comment: using var instead of the specific type doesn't help.

Comment: It is itemID.
IMy_Custom_Type is the interface generated using  TDS.

Comment: Can you put class/interface definion for IMy_Custom_Type?

Comment: @pijemcolu Using `var` makes no difference, it will be strongly typed and compiled to IL [exactly the same](http://jeremybytes.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/demystifying-var-keyword-in-c.html). Hover over the var in Visual Studio and it will tell you the type.

Comment: @SitecoreClimber Added the definition for IMy_Custom_Type

Comment: You are (very) sure that the item you are testing (itemId) is from template `IMy_Custom_TypeConstants.TemplateIdString`?

Comment: @Gatogordo : Yes I'm (very) sure that, item I'm trying to load is of type IMy_Custom_Type

Answer (score 0):

Create Class called `My_Custom_Type`  implement your interface `IMy_Custom_Type`, and add all the properties from other interfaces to this class:

```
public class My_Custom_Type : IMy_Custom_Type 
{
// IMy_Custom_Type  properties
// IGlassBase  properties
// IMetadata properties
// IBase_Background_Image properties
}
```

then try to cast your object like this :

```
var myCustomObj=SitecoreContext.GetItem<My_Custom_Type>(itemId);
```

Comment: Looks like they are using TDS generated Glass models, so the concrete implementation would also be created (by default). But interfaces should also work, and it's often preferable to code against interfaces.

Comment: We have implementation of the interface (auto generated via TDS).